# Определение кириллических букв в аббревиатуре

Tags: javascript

Можно ли при помощи JS определить, есть ли в аббревиатуре, например такой "FCAG125A/RR125BV3", кириллические буквы?
Если да, то какие свойства и методы помогут решить такую задачку?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вариант можно использовать [регулярные выражения](https://learn.javascript.ru/regular-expressions-javascript) и метод [.test()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test).

Достаточно будет следующего примера кода:

```
let regexp = /[а-яё]/i;
regexp.test(string);
```

И пример результата:

```js
let string = 'ваываывЫФАЫВАsdkfjlsdkfer';
let string1 = 'dkfjlsdkfer';
let string2 = 'ваываыв';
let string3 = '34234234';

let regexp = /[а-яё]/i;

console.log(regexp.test(string));
console.log(regexp.test(string1));
console.log(regexp.test(string2));
console.log(regexp.test(string3));
```

Comment: Возможно, лучше использовать флаг **i** - *ignore case*. Тогда запись бует короче и нагляднее `/[а-яё]/i`.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko спасибо за улучшение, приму к сведению, исправлю

Comment: А если необходимо найденные кириллические символы окрасить в другой цвет, достаточно будет метода test() или надо будет использовать exec() ?

Comment: @ikar, одного метода `test()` будет недостаточно, так как он только возвращает `true` или `false` в зависимости от того, есть ли там русские символы. А чтобы окрасить кириллицу надо еще и строку разбить на подстроки, скорее всего лучше подойдет не `exec()`, а [match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) и оборачивать в `<span>`, чтобы покрасить отдельные (это мое видение картины). Для такого случая, мне кажется, лучше задать новый вопрос.